# Content overflow out of bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a problem with the bootstrap modal. I want put a map that shows routing on the left side in the modal, and the route information on the right side. The map works fine, however the routing information overflows out of the modal. My modal code is below:

```
 function displayRoute() {
            var map2Prop = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8142, 144.9632),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var mapRouting = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("maprouting"), map2Prop);
            $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                displayRoute();
            });
            /* ----------- for routing ---------- */
            directionsDisplay.setMap(mapRouting);
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions"));
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
            document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function () {
                calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
            });
            /* ----------- for routing below----- */
        }
        // Direction
        function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {

            var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
            directionsService.route({
                origin: {lat: currentLat, lng: currentLng},
                destination: {lat: destnLat, lng: destnLng},
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
            }, function (response, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                } else {
                    alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
                }
            });
        }
        //Remove space
        function trim(str) {
            return str.replace(/(^\s+)|(\s+$)/g, "");
        }
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="gPMap" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div>Suburb:</div>
            <input type="text" id="suburbInput" value="clayton"></input><br>
            <div>Language:</div>
            <input type="text" id = "languageInput"></input><br>
            <button onclick="showGPs()">Show GPs</button>
        </div>
    </div>
     <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div id="maprouting" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div id="directions">
                                    <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
                                    <select id="mode">
                                        <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
                                        <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
                                        <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
                                        <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The result is like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV3OT.jpg)
Need help here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Which maps plugin do you use?

Comment: @MarcoS I use map api for map and display route.

Comment: It's not clear, to me... Add the code you use to load the map...

Comment: Do you want to fit map data to your modal? Or scrolling is ok?

Comment: @SeokjunHong Yes scrolling is better, just don't overflow

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hu52cuda/3/ check this fiddle. i have removed container and fixed width from your code

Comment: Isn't `overflow-x: scroll` working? Have you already tried?

Comment: @RavinSinghD Thank you so much!! It is working !